# Weak solution of wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For a linear wave equation
$$
u_{tt} - \Delta u = f
$$
with zero boundary conditions, a weak solution $u$ belongs to $L^2(0,T;H^1_0)$ with $u_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2)$ and $u_{tt} \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$.

I understand $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0)$ and $u_{tt} \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ come from the PDE, but what is the motivation for $u_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2)$?